# How to count projects active at given date

Tags: excel

I have an excel table with some projects each one having a start and end date (some are still open but that's not the point at this time). I'm trying to summarize in a pivot table for each calendar week how many projects were open, but I can't find a way to do that. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried adding headers with different dates to the table and for each line (project) check whether they were open or not at that time (status 1 or 0) and for each column sum the open ones, but this becomes tedious if I want to summarize in a pivot table at a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to create a new column, with a formula to calculate if a project is still open, the formula should be something like:

```
=AND(NOW()>=B5;NOW()<=C5)
```

where `B5` containing start date and `C5` containing end date.

If you want to use this formula for a particular day within the week, you can use this formula to check if your day is a Monday: `=WEEKDAY(NOW();1)`.

Comment: Hi Dominique, thanks for your answer. That would be the solution if I was looking to find all currently active projects. But I want to have it for every monday in the past year (so for each calendar week, which and how many projects were open).

Comment: @user3661678: I've adopted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that data are structure as follow:

[image]

I create as pivot table:

**Filters:**

- End Column

**Rows:**

- Start Week Number Column
- Project Column

[image]